# sqlite3 registration database not updating

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask

I'm making a simple registration page in Flask using sqlite. I did a test run manually and this worked:

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
c = db.cursor()

username = "bb"
password = "vv"

c.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)", (username, password))
db.commit()
```

But I can't get this to work in my app.py (below is a greatly simplified version)

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form.get("username")
        password = request.form.get("password")
        confirmation = request.form.get("confirmation")

        try:
            c.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)", (username, password))
            db.commit()
            return render_template("login.html")
        except:
            return apology("username is already registered")

    else:
        return render_template("register.html")
```

I get redirected to my apology page (Username is already registered). My database.db is empty :( Any help would be appreciated, new to the community and coding.

Comment: why dont you add some "print exception details" in your `except` section to see what is actually happening?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i'm new to try/except. I did 'traceback.print_exc()' and found the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue: "SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread."

I just added the cursor and now it works

```
c = c = db.cursor()
```